# missing interpolation type in react native android

Tags: react-native

this my `LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CustomLayoutAnimation);`  here is

```
var CustomLayoutAnimation = {
  duration: 10,
  create: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity
  },
  update: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.curveEaseInEaseOut
  }
};
```

in my constructor

```
constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&
        UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    }
```

but ios working fine in android getting error [image]

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 6):

Might be late but hopefully itll help someone else.

I recently faced a similar issue when trying to work with LayoutAnimation in react native. Going through the source code gave me a few ideas. In your case it might be the curveEaseInEaseOut, the type in the LayoutAnimation.js file is easeInEaseOut.

This is how i define my custom animation type.

```
const CustomLayoutLinear = {
  duration: 300,
  create: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
  },
  update: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
  },
  delete: {
    duration: 50,
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
  },
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. Having a duration of 0 also causes the error above for me.

Comment: For me switching out `curveEaseInEaseOut` with `easeInEaseOut` worked